# Implementing 2 interfaces in java in cordova plugins

Tags: java, cordova

I have a java class that requires me to extend two interfaces, may I know if there's a way to do so?

what I have tried is this.

```
public class BLE extends CordovaPlugin implements RFStarBLEBroadcastReceiver, ServiceConnection
```

Comment: I don't  know about Cordova plugins but as far as java goes I don't see any issue in your code, is there any error message?

Comment: @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam hi, pls see my revised body

Comment: The is no edit.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam - sorry, when i wanted to edit, i realize that I simply left out a couple of important syntax which causes it to crash upon running, thanks for trying to help!!!